# Arduino array programming

Tags: c++, arduino

I am learning Arduino, and I have a question. I am currently working on a NFC project and I am stuck.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <PN532_I2C.h>
#include <PN532.h>   
#include <NfcAdapter.h>

PN532_I2C pn532_i2c(Wire);
NfcAdapter nfc = NfcAdapter(pn532_i2c);  
int i;

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  nfc.begin();
}

void loop() {
 for (i = 0; i < 5; i = i + 1){
    delay(1000);
    if(nfc.tagPresent()){
      int myPins[] = {2, 4, 8, 3, 6};
      Serial.println(myPins[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

When I place the NFC chip on the reader, I am getting an output as 2 then after a `delay(1000)` I am getting an output 4. The issue I am facing is, if I'm not placing the NFC chip on the reader, after `delay(1000)` it is skipping to the next value and prints 3 the next time I place the NFC on the reader. But I want to print 8 even after a delay of 1000. I am stuck here.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Yes Mr.Bob , i was able to resolve the issue . Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it worked for you, or post your own answer (which you can accept later) if something else did the trick so that future readers know how to solve this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `while`-loop and only increment when the chip is found:

```
 int i = 0;

 while (i < 5)
 {
    delay(1000);
    if(nfc.tagPresent())
    {
      int myPins[] = {2, 4, 8, 3, 6};
      Serial.println(myPins[i]);
      i = i + 1; // increment only if tag is present.
    }
  }
```

Note that `myPins` could be defined once outside of the loop, which would make the loop faster:

```
 int i = 0;
 int myPins[] = {2, 4, 8, 3, 6};

 while (i < 5)
 {
    delay(1000);
    if(nfc.tagPresent())
    {
      Serial.println(myPins[i]);
      i = i + 1; // increment only if tag is present.
    }
  }
```